# Rooted Android Phone - Add Latest Google Play Store to System App for future factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, root-access

I rooted my Android Phone and deleted some unwanted apps with google play store, google play services and google text to speech.

Now how to add these apps again (latest version) as a system app for future factory reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Google Play store here [ http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1996995 ].
Install it from file manager by clicking APK file. Convert to System app via [TitaniumBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) if you've already bought it as this feature is only available in PRO version. Or use this app [ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover ] which is free. You can also move to /system/app folder manually and then set the right permission [and generate odex file] but using app to convert app to system app is safer option.

Comment: The system-app-mover is available here for non-Google users: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.j4velin.systemappmover

Comment: Not working.. I have followed process which you described and then I factory reset phone, these apps are pre installed but not working when I open.

Comment: Also 2-3 errors coming very frequently.. com.google.process.gapps has stopped working, google play strore has stopped working etc.

Comment: You mentioned that system app mover creates an odex file when apk moved from user apps to system apps. but this file not created automatically.

Comment: I mean you may need to create odex if you are using odexed rom. I don't know system app mover will generate one or not. But lucky patcher can create odex for you. Also, please remove your installed gapps and try with this. [ http://en.miui.com/thread-3998-1-1.html ]

Answer (score 0):

Download file for Play store and then download and install the [Link2SD from Google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). 
Now open Link2SD app and go to App file which you want to convert to system files and long press you will see the option to convert file as system. 
Press ok and reboot.

Comment: In the question it says that Play Store has been removed; how would the user install an app from the Play Store if Play Store is not installed on the phone?

Comment: for rooted phone
download play store convert it to system app with link2sd then odex google play using lucky patcher.